# How can I create a dynamic grid with animated elements withflutter?

Tags: flutter

how can I generate a speed indicator with svg or png graphic in flutter.

I need a background graphic, about it several moveable items like a needle. How could I display several of these elements on a page (speed / engine speed / temperature)? How can I create a dynamic grid with animated elements with flutter?

Comment: Please mention what you have tried so far and this question have multiple questions, please be specific where do you need help? getting svg / png image? animation in flutter? or dynamic grids?

Comment: I have done only a bluetooth connection and a simple text page to visualize the data in text form. Now I want to make animated graphics for these data.